# Groups with cyclic radicals

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a torsion-free group. For an element $g \in G \setminus \{1_G\}$ we define the radical of $g$ in $G$ as
$$
   Rad_G(g) = \left\{r \in G \mid r^a = g^b \mbox{ for some } a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}\right\} \cup \{1_G\}.
$$

For which torsion-free groups can we show that $Rad_G(g)$ is an infinite cyclic subgroup of $G$ for every nontrivial element? So far I have been able to establish it for the following classes:

- residually finitely generated torsion-free nilpotent groups,
- torsion-free hyperbolic groups,
- relatively hyperbolic groups (in the sense of Bowdich), where the associated subgroups already have the property (this includes for example toral relatively-hyperbolic groups).

Are there any easy examples I am missing?

EDIT:
there is also an equivalent definition.

For an element of infinite order we define
$$
plog_G(g) = \max\{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid r^k = g \mbox{ for some } r\in G\}.
$$
If $plog_G(g)$ is finite, then it makes sense to define
$$
\sqrt[G]{g} = \{r \in G \mid r^{plog_G(g)} = g\}.
$$
For a torsion-free group $G$ and an element $g \in G \setminus\{1\}$ the following are equivalent:

- $Rad_G(g)$ is an infinite cyclic subgroup of $G$,
- $|\sqrt[G]{g}| = 1$ and $plog_G(g^n) = n\cdot plog_G(g)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: "Clearly a subgroup": no, it's not a subgroup in general. For instance in the fundamental group of the Klein bottle $\langle x,y|x^2=y^2\rangle$, both $x$ and $y$ belong to $Rad_G(x)$, but $xy$ does not. Stlll the question makes sense (you're asking when is the subset $Rad_G(g)$ a cyclic subgroup for every $g\neq 1$.

Comment: Of course you have finite direct products of such groups. Other examples are torsion-free finitely generated subgroups in $\mathrm{SL}_2(A)$, where $A$ is is the ring of integral elements in $\mathbf{Q}$. For instance, this includes torsion-free finite-index subgroups in $SL_2(\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}])$, which are far from relatively hyperbolic and are not virtually residually torsion-free nilpotent.

Comment: Actually, the property of having "cyclic radicals" is preserved w.r.t. to graph products and amalgamation along a common retract, but that's not easy to see. I am using this property to study certain behaviour and I was wondering which groups do have it, on top of the obvious ones.

Comment: As is usual in MO, you missed the torsion-free Tarski monsters (and many other groups where the centralizer of every non-identity element is cyclic). You also missed the R. Thompson group $F$.

Comment: By the way, your property is equivalent to a combination of two properties, which are worth being treated separately: (a) that $Rad_G(g)$ is locally cyclic for every $g\neq 1$. This means that any two elements with a common power have a common root. (b) every locally cyclic subgroup is cyclic. For instance, any torsion -free subgroup of $SL_2$ satisfies (a). And (a) is a 1st-order invariant, since it's equivalent to the condition that any two elements with a common power commute. Hence it's equivalent to a combination of infinitely many 1st-order formulas, and passes to inductive limits.

Comment: It seems that every finitely generated torsion-free linear group in characteristic zero has a finite index subgroup satisfying (a). This is (would be?) an improvement of Selberg's lemma, and I think it can be proved with a little $p$-adic analysis. In particular, $SL_3(\mathbf{Z})$ has a finite index subgroup satisfying your condition.

Comment: @MarkSapir thank you for poiting these out. As a common MO user, I'm not too familiar with Tarski mosters, I'll give it a look.

Comment: @YCor you are spot on I added alternative definition as well. The original motivation was to study separability of cyclic subgroups in pro-$p$ topology. By necessity, if $H < G$ is $p$-closed in $G$ then it must be $p$-isolated. Informally, $H$ is closed with respect to taking $q$th roots, where $q$ is a prime distinct from $p$: $f^q \in H$ implies $f \in H$. The idea was to come up with a notion that allows me to give a nice characterisation of cyclic subgroups with such property. In this case, I can show that $\langle g \rangle$ is $p$-isolated iff $plog_G(g)$ is a power of $p$.